# does g++ compiler treats constexpr functions as regular in a case their return value isnt being used?

Tags: c++, g++, constexpr

I have tried to see a compiled code of a cpp constexpr function compiled by g++.
I saw that if the function isnt return nothing than the compiler treats it as a regular function but if it return a value and I assign this value to a constexpr variable, only then it is being calculated at compile time.

Code example:

```
constexpr int func(int x){
   return x!=0 ? 1: throw "Error";
}

int main(){
    func(2);
}
```

and the compiler output:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
mov     edi, 2
call    func(int)
mov     eax, 0
pop     rbp
ret
```

As you can see it calls func at runtime. In contrast if I assing the function result to a constexpr:

```
constexpr int func(int x){
    return x!=0 ? 1: throw "Error";
}

int main(){
   constexpr int x = func(2);
}
```

and the compiler output:

```
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
    mov     eax, 0
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Can someone explain me why this assignment is needed for the compiler to evaluate the function at compile time instead of at run time?

Comment: TIL you can have `int` and `void` expressions as 2nd and 3rd operand of conditional

Comment: @M.M Only if the `void` expression is a `throw` expression, so it doesn't need to be considered in the conditional expression's result type, given that the `throw`, if executed, can never result in a value for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is allowed to decide whether or not to evaluate the constexpr function at compile time or run time. Only if the function is used in a context that requires compile time constant expressions (such as initializing a `constexpr` variable with the result), the compiler *must* evaluate the function at compile time.

In your first example, this is not the case, and as you probably compiled in debug mode, the function is called at run-time as every other function would be.

A quote from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) (highlighting by me):

> The constexpr specifier declares that it is **possible** to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time. Such variables and functions can then be used where only compile time constant expressions are allowed (provided that appropriate function arguments are given).

If you compile your first example with e.g. `-O3` you'll see that the function call is optimized away.

Comment: Whats weird is that if I comile it eith O3 then it seems that the compiler just inlines my function and not really avaluate it at compile time.

Comment: For example if I pass the function the value 0(which I hopefully wanted to cause a compile time error in a constexpr function like this) it inlines the throw to the main and throws exception at run time

Comment: If the code path in a constexpr function throws, then that function can't be used in a context requireing compile time constant expressions. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/dRXo4t

Answer (score 1):

I compiled the code below to find out if gcc 11.2 optimizes constexpr functions:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
constexpr double pi(){
 double a=0.;
 for(int i=1;i<100000;i+=4)a+=1./i-1./(i+2);
 return a*4;
}
    
int main(){
 constexpr int pi2=pi()*100;
 enum {pi3=pi2};
 cout<<pi3<<endl;
}
```

Disassembly is as follows:

```
# temp.cpp:10: int main(){
        call    __main   #
 # temp.cpp:11:  constexpr int pi2=pi()*100;
        movl    $314, -4(%rbp)   #, pi2
 # temp.cpp:13:  cout<<pi3<<endl;
        movl    $314, %edx       #,
        movq    .refptr._ZSt4cout(%rip), %rax    #, tmp85
        movq    %rax, %rcx       # tmp85,
        call    _ZNSolsEi        #
        movq    %rax, %rcx       #, _1
 # temp.cpp:13:  cout<<pi3<<endl;
        movq    .refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_(%rip), %rax   #, tmp86
        movq    %rax, %rdx       # tmp86,
        call    _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E         #
 # temp.cpp:14: }
        movl    $0, %eax         #, _7
        addq    $48, %rsp        #,
        popq    %rbp     #
        ret
```

As a result, gcc can evaluate constexpr functions in compile time.

If longer calculations needed, gcc flags `-fconstexpr-*` should be increased. But I observed that compile time calculation takes more time than (`-O3` flag) execution time calculations.

If longer calculations needed, I suggest,

- writing code to produce code (like calculating `pi` in the sample above),
- compiling and running that code,
- compiling the produced code with the rest of code.

Writing a `makefile` to do the steps above will be helpful.